# How to implement geocoding using nominatim

Tags: openlayers, geocoding, openstreetmap, nominatim

Hi I am new to openstreet map and nomintim....I have found what I was looking for in the following link.....But I am not sure how to implement it...I just need to get the geocoding details like if we search a place I need to get the lat and long and also suggested more results like shown in the left column in the following example I don't want to plot it in a map.. Any help will be appreciated

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search

Answer (score 4):

Have you searched first? The first result on Google:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Try making your requests to this URL:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=ADDRESS_HERE&format=XML/JSON/HTML

This has geocoding results in it.

Comment: Does Nominatim have secure http (https)?

Comment: [http service](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?format=json&json_callback=renderBasicSearchNarrative&q=westminster+abbey) works perfectly whereas [https service](https://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?format=json&json_callback=renderBasicSearchNarrative&q=westminster+abbey) showed me an error-This webpage is not available (This happened in normal browser).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Detailed Desctiption of Nominatim Class In android Java file! 
As I was Suspecting that is the only way to integrate it to the Android Studio! Hope it makes Senese

```
http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMBonusPack/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/location/GeocoderNominatim.java
```

Also If You work On a Android Studio or eclipse You can Add the Library

from  [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/fr.dudie/nominatim-api/2.0%22here%22).